# Cual es la solucion a este código?

Tags: javascript

El ejercicio dice: Hacer una función llamada “mayor” que reciba dos números enteros y
devuelva el mayor de ellos o cero si son iguales.

Yo intenté hacer esto pero no devuelve nada.

```js
let num1 = 15;
let num2 = 10;

function mayor(num1,num2){
    if(num1 > num2){
        console.log(num1);
    } 
    else if(num1 < num2){
        console.log(num2);      
    } 
    else{
        return 0;
    }
};

mayor();
```

Comment: Está raro que definas la función con dos parámetros y no le entregues nada, no?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que `console.log()` NO devuelve nada, solo imprime en pantalla. Tienes una combinación bien rara entre `console.log()` y `return` que no tienen mucho sentido. Sin contar lo de "llamarla sin parámetros" que ya te mencionaron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas empezando con esto de la programación ¿no? Es más fácil de lo que te pueda parecer ahora. Te corrijo el ejercicio

```
function mayor(num1,num2){
    let maximo = 0;
    if(num1 > num2){
        maximo = num1; 
    } 
    else if(num1 < num2){
        maximo = num1;
    } 
return maximo
};

mayor(15,10);
```

Lo de la declaración de num1 y num2 no sirve para nada. Invocas a la función (mandas que se ejecute) enviándole los argumentos 15 y 10 en estecaso. Esos valores se le guardan en los los argumentos de la función: num1 y num2. El resto creo que lo manejas bien, los condicionales if. Te quito un else que facilita el código. De entrada suponemos que num1 y num2 son iguales y maximo es 0, si no lo son pues maxmo tomara el valor que le sorresponda ( el mayor de los dos nueros) y luego devuelve maximo.